# Litecoin API или как принимать LTC на сайте?

Tags: php, blockchain

Подключил на сайт прием BTC через API. Также стоит задача принимать LTC. В Интернете ничего толком не нашел по этому поводу, много инфы по BTC, а по LTC нашел только то, что принимать его можно через API Блокчейна, но не нашел, как.
Вопрос — как принимать LTC?

Спасибо

Comment: То же самое что и обычный эквайринг от Bitcoin - ищете поставщика этих услуг, регистрируете номер своего кошелька и вперёд. Основной принцип работы у них это ассоциация номера заказа с его суммой и механизмы оплаты на определённый кошелёк с этим идентификатором.

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, подробнее?

Comment: https://gourl.io/litecoin-payment-gateway-api.html а также https://themerkle.com/top-4-alternative-ways-to-accept-litecoin-payments/

Comment: Я использую https://biwse.com/ для приема LTC у себя на сайте. Сервис отличный отзывчивая тех поддержка. Рекомендую